# Seleccionar registos entre duas datas

Tags: sql, sybase

Boas, tenho uma view " GP_Vw_Cons_Faltas " que contem a data inicial e a data final de quando um cliente falta.

Eu quero recolher todos os registos de um determinado cliente num determinado periodo de tempo.

Estou a tentar usar a seguinte query:

```
select *
    from GP_Vw_Cons_Faltas 
    where DataInicio > "01/01/2015" AND DataFim < "01/10/2016" AND Codigo = 65
```

Que não me retorna todos os valores correspondentes ao intervalo, alguem tem uma solução?

SGBD : Sybase

Colunas da view:

DataInicio
DataFim 
Codigo

Comment: Você não informou o `SGBD` nem os dados que você tem na tabela

Comment: Fi-lo agora, obrigado

Comment: Como estão declaradas as colunas DataInicio e DataFim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marco, bom dia!

Olhando seu problema, me veio na cabeça a questão seguinte:

Existe dentro da estrutura em que as ferramentas de banco de dados foram construidos a questão que diferencia DATA de DATETIME.

*Data* é o valor do dia, exemplo: 01/01/2019
*Datetime* é o valor do dia e hora/minuto/segundo, ou seja, uma fração do tempo

Se o Sybase entender o campo como datetime na comparação, ele deverá comparar com hora/minuto/segundo, isso gera alguns problemas pra bater valores.
Sugiro fazer um cast/convert para um padrão de data antes de fazer a comparação para efeito de testes.

PS: Tive esse mesmo problema no MSSQL

Comment: Era exatamente isso, muito obrigado!

Comment: Imagina, é uma issue que os campos de data sempre carregam.

Answer (score 1):

Escreva o comando passando as datas usando o `BETWEEN`:

```js
select *
from GP_Vw_Cons_Faltas 
where DataInicio BETWEEN '01/01/2015' AND '01/10/2016';
```

Comment: Tenho duas colunas, não funciona

Answer (score 0):

Você tem 2 colunas datas? Uma DataInicio e outra DataFim?
Se sim tem que ser assim :

```html
select *
from GP_Vw_Cons_Faltas
WHERE `DataInicio` > '2019/03/14' and `DataFim` < '2019/03/14'
AND Codigo = 65
```

Se for uma só

```html
select *
from GP_Vw_Cons_Faltas
WHERE `data` BETWEEN '2019/03/14' AND '2019/03/14'
AND Codigo = 65
```

Comment: Não resulta, não me da os valores todos entre os intervalos. Sim, tenho duas colunas